# How to disable the title field in a content type?

Tags: nodes

i'm using drupal 7
How to disable the title field in a content type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module is what you're after:

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.

Comment: Actually every node must have a title. But you can hide it from the user and user auto nodetitle, or some other way in hook_node_pesave to give it a title.

Comment: is there any way to change title field type (exp float) ?

Comment: The title is a *property* of the node entity rather than a *field*...it's pretty much hard-coded into the node entity hook implementations. You might be able to override it but in my experience fiddling with those parts of the system can get very messy

Comment: If you wanted to do that, you could create a float_title field and then use autonodetitle to grab the value/token of that field and then populate the real title with it (I would imagine internally this would mean you'd have a float in the field and the text version of it in the title) and then hide it from the user so you don't have duplicate displays, but that seems rather ugly/excessive given how typeless php is (unless you really need this value in a view or something?)

Comment: Also if you want to turn the title into a field, you could look into the Title module, which was created to make titles regular fields for the Entity Translation project. http://drupal.org/project/title

Answer (score 1):

As Clive suggests, [auto_nodetitle](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) is a good module for removing the title from the form. If you wanted to serialize the content [serial](http://drupal.org/project/serial) is a good simple module that would do the job that jimajamma explains but with an automated serial number. Then finally, the simplest way without any custom code to hide the title field from display totally (or put any fields where you want) is [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide the title for an entity you can try the following.  (Note, I don't think this is the best method and I am open to suggestions that make this better).  Put this in your theme's template.php

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

  if(isset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['ENTITY_TYPE'])) {
   drupal_set_title('');
  }
}
```

What this does is if the entity is being displayed in the ['content'] region of the page, in much the same way a node would be displayed in the content region, then change the title to nothing.  You need to replace THEME with the name of your of your theme and ENTITY_TYPE with the entity whose title you want to suppress.  If it does not work, go to page.tpl.php and add `<pre> <?php print_r($vars['page']) ?> </pre>`, reload the page of interest, and work your way down the tree to find the path into the array that identifies the the thing that you want to suppress.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in D7 and D8 (where it is in core) is the [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module which lets you treat Title like a field eg set Title to hidden in the content type Display pane, set it to show in a Block with the [Field as Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldblock) module to pop it in to a sidebar etc

The module contributors say:

> While working on the new content translation system for Drupal 7, we (the Drupal core i18n team) faced the need to convert node titles to the Field API in order to make nodes fully translatable. We were not able to make this happen in Drupal 7 core, so we decided to find a solution for this in contrib: the idea is replacing node titles with fields à la Automatic Nodetitles.